# Какая библиотека для параллакс эффекта кроссбраузерна?

Tags: html, jquery, css, parallax

Привет всем 
**Проблема** : на сайте должен быть параллакс эффект. Я подключил Parallax.js, на основных браузерах он смотрится неплохо, но в Сафари происходит дикая вакханалия.
**Вопрос**: Подскажите хорошую JS библиотеку, которая будет работать во всех браузерах корректно.

Спасибо

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, информацию о том какие браузеры вы поддерживаете с их версиями, ибо я могу гарантировать что смогу найти браузер в котором не будет работать практически любая библиотека.

Comment: @Arnial Все как обычно, ослик 9-10, главное, что бы в сафари работало не топорно

Comment: В какой версии сафари тестируте, какую ОС используете для тестирования?

Comment: Не знаю, я читал, что это глобальная проблема. El Capitan последний, сафари последняя

Comment: https://yandex.kz/search/?text=parallax%20library&lr=35393  вот в поиске этих библиотек балом : выбирайте

Comment: @Geyan вопрос же не в том, чтобы найти хоть какую-то библиотеку, а в том, чтобы найти библиотеку, которая будет хорошо работать в сафари. Воздержитесь от посылов в yandex/google, пожалуйста.

Comment: вы хотите что бы то что там написано я просто перепечатал ? просто почитайте о этом в поисковиках

Comment: @Geyan вместо моего вопроса лучше прочтите учебник по пунктуации

Comment: умничайте сколько угодно , ответа вам ни кто не даст , для этого есть поисковики , могу научить как такое писать , к примеру : parallax cross browser compatibility, и ваши по*..ки мне фиолетовы

Comment: годика два назад мучался с параллаксом, в итоге  скопировал код (сейчас даже не помню откуда) в сафари под mac os работает, только загрузка картинок глючит. http://uilliams.specialview.ru/ посмотрите файлы http://uilliams.specialview.ru/js/jquery.parallax.js  и http://uilliams.specialview.ru/js/global.js может поможет